# Cual es la mejor manera de cargar un html determinado según la resolución del dispositivo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo una web. Uno de los diseños funciona bien en pantallas grandes pero por su estructura es imposible de maquetar de forma responsible, por eso he hecho dos sitios con el mismo contenido. Quería saber cual es la mejor forma de cargar uno u otro según la resolución del dispositivo.

Gracias!

Comment: le sugiero que utilice bootstrap para la maquetacion de su sitios web ayuda mucho con la parte resposible en cualquier resolución de pantalla   https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con este codigo que hice segun la pregunta planteada, aqui se obtiene la resolución desde **JavaScript**, modificalo para que lo adaptes a tu sistema.

Aqui esta el codigo:

```js
               // resolucion 
                /*
                -- para trabajar con ancho de ventana
                     window.outerWidth;
                --  para trabajar con ancho de pantalla
                     screen.width
                 */
                var ancho = window.outerWidth;
                var ruta = null;
                if (ancho < 1024) 
                     {
                        document.write ("Pequeña " + screen.width) 
                        ruta ='pequena.html';
                       
                     }
                     
                else if (ancho < 1280) 
                     {
                        document.write ("Mediana " + screen.width) 
                        ruta ='mediana.html';
                     }
                     
                else 
                    {
                        document.write ("Grande " + window.outerWidth)
                        ruta ='grande.html';
                    }
                       
                // ir a la ruta segun resulucion
                var pausa = setTimeout(function() {
                    document.location.href = ruta;
                }, 2000);
```

Explicacion:

A) Para usar la resolucion ancho de la pantalla usa: `screen.width`
B) Para usar la resolucion ancho  de la ventana usar: `window.outerWidth`

El codigo es sencillo: 
1) se declara dos variables, la primera es para tomar la fuente de la resolucion y la otra es para la ruta.

2) Los `if() else if()` else son para evaluar tres tipos de ancho de resolucion. (en tu caso con solo usar el if() else ya tienes para los dos tipos de resolucion. deacuerdo a la seleccionada muestra en pantalla el tipo y valor, se asigna la ruta a dirigir.

3) La variable pausa ejecuta un `SetTimeOut()` para dar un retraso para la redireccion. En este caso las rutas que te aconsejo a usar deberan estar separadas por un subdirectorio para cada dispositivo.